# Speaker static unaffected by volume or audio input

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a set of KRK Rokit 5 speakers (they are self powered studio monitors, probably about 5 years old.

They have a fair bit of irregular buzzing/static noise. Not extremeley loud, but enough that when I sit near them it is quite distracting.

I noticed that it happens whether or not the speakers are connected to an audio input (which would be via an RCA cable right into a headphone jack). And it also is independent of the volume adjustment on the back of the speaker. I have tried a few different power cords, including a surge protector.

I'm not sure what makes sense here, other than maybe it is an issue with the speakers themselves. Both in the pair do it, but one is worse...

Comment: It could be a ground loop. What else is on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be a ground loop if it isn't connected to an audio input!
My guess it the self-power has a (or some) bad capacitors.
My bet is that if you take it apart you will see electrolytics with convex tops - they should be flat or concave . This is a common problem. Try Digikey or Mouser for replacements. Be conscious of the physical size. The voltage and capacitance must be the same or higher, but higher isn't going to add anything, just convenience if they don't have the exact value you need.
I just replaced 2 in a refer board and 2 in my TV.

Comment: I am no electrician.. not even close. Are you talking about the speaker itself? is it possibly caused by power cable mismatch going into the speakers?

Comment: whatever is powering the speaker. It is either a power block or it is internal to one of the speaker enclosures. If the AC cord goes directly to the speaker then the issue is internal to the speaker that it goes to. If it goes to a block then to the speaker, replace the block if it is a separate item. IE with a connector to the speaker. If it is in the speaker u will need to take them to a repair shop unless u know someone who can do the above.